# Swift Json into array for tableview

Tags: json, swift, url

Been coding in PHP for 10 years plus, and trying to write my first IOS app now, but man oh man, is the learning curve steep and difficult!!!!  I am trying for two weeks already to get a simple url displaying Json into an array then into a tableview and I'm stumped. Any demos I find are either in Objective C or even in Swift but not up to date for Xcode 6.1.  I have watched tutorials and have a good book from Apress (published last November) but find nothing. I have my tableview set up and can have it display from a staticly built array correctly, so I don't need any help with that part. All I need is an up to date example of parsing a json file from a url and throwing that into an array I can build my table rows from.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to get you going:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://date.jsontest.com")

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let fetchData: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
            println("\(json)")
        }
    }

    fetchData.resume()
```

Comment: What would be the name of the array I use to build my rows in your example?

Comment: json is a dictionary of json objects, so in this example you would do something like json["time"] json["date"]

Comment: Ah, I missed that part "var json". So the total in the array I guess then would be json.count ?

Comment: Really depends on you json model. Just set a break point on the line and have a look inside what gets returned?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything ready-built that does all of that, at least not in Swift. I wrote some code to parse local JSON data into collection objects. That part is quite simple.

The code to parse JSON data into an array might look like this:

```
if let quizNSArray: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(sourceJSONData,
  options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0),
  error: nil) as? NSArray
{
  //If JSON conversion worked this code executes.
}
```

You'll need to write code that creates an NSURLRequest, then an NSURLConnection, and submits and async GET request, then collects the results in an NSData object. Alternately you could use the NSURLConnection class method that takes a completion block. (It's called `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`). I could write that code in Objective-C in my sleep, but haven't had to write it in swift yet.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try that first thing tomorrow. Yeah, problem is you guys who have been coding in objective C for years have it easy, because it still works in Xcode. It's people trying to start now in Swift are stumped a lot. Apple's own developer section is so difficult to understand for beginners in my opinion, it may as well have been written in double Dutch!!